# Add to specific indices to an array based on a condition in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array `S 440x120` in dimensions. There is another array `T 440x1`.

I need to append say rows of S to another array T1 based on the following conditions

1. The rows appended must be from index say 100 to 200 in S.
2. Only those rows with `T(100:200)==1` should be included. This means that if `T(100)=0` then `S(100,:)` should not be included and if `T(101)=1` then `S(101,:)` should be included.

I tried using the following but it failed due to obvious reasons as it includes from the first index and not from the 100th.

```
T1=S(T(100:200)==1,:);
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this in matlab apart from writing a whole loop?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: When you say "add all columns of S to another array", do you mean add _each_ column of S or add the _sum_ of all columns of S?

Comment: Each column of S is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it. You only need to add an offset to the numeric (not logical) indices:

```
N = 100;
M = 200;
result = S(N-1+find(T(N:M)==1),:);
```

Comment: Uh Oh! Ill try that. Could you please comment the code so I can understand what it actually does? :P

Comment: Thanks! Why the sum though? I think I got my answer from this though. Will try it out.

Comment: @SohaibI You said "add those colummns"... by "add" did you mean "sum" or simply "include"?

Comment: I don't mean add as in addition! Ill make the edit in my question. I mean add as in append to that.

Comment: I have already written that as an answer in my question. This does not work. It includes rows from the first index in S and not from the 100th index.

Answer (score 2):

How about `T1=S([zeros(99,1); T(100:200)]==1,:);`?

Comment: Not sure if the zeros should be a row or column matrix. Either this or `[zeros(1,99) T(100:200)]`. You use the zeros to ignore the first 99 elements of `S` and start at index 100.

Comment: it should be 101. Ill try it out and report back.

Comment: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals?

Comment: @SohaibI Make sure you don't have a typo, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
idx = find(T==1);
idx = idx(idx>=100 & idx<=200);

S(idx,:)
```

Comment: You could save the first 99 `==1` comparisons... :-)

Comment: Can't mark all answers correct unfortunately :P
@LuisMendo I think you took that find() function idea from here ;)
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @SohaibI Not really :-) When you want to add an offset to a set of indices, the indices have to be in numeric form, not in logical form; and `find` does just that. What took me some time was to understand the question ;-)